# Where can I get TeamCity source code

Tags: teamcity

I've heard that TeamCity has a open source licence, but where i can get the source code, or TeamCity does not open source?

In this link we can see the open source license, does it means the license just for open source projects?

http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/buy/index.jsp

Comment: Yes, the open source license it refers to is *for* open source projects. Team City itself is not (so far as I'm aware) open source itself.

Answer (score 3):

It seems TeamCity is not a opensource project, the opensource license is just for the opensource projects,to allow these projects use TeamCity